# Regarding the organization of data for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, render

Is it appropriate to have 1 vertex array object for every model in the scene? How many VAOs are you allowed to have?

Comment: How do you define "appropriate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to have 1 vertex array object for every model in the scene?

Yes, but often collection of low vertex count objects sharing properties are collected into a single VAO.

> How many VAOs are you allowed to have?

As many as you like to and can be represented by GLuint.